# Обязательно ли вторичное значение слова — переносное?

Tags: лексика, лексикология

В любом ли случае вторичное значение слова появилось вследствие переноса наименования с одного предмета, действия, явления, свойства на другие? Может ли быть, к примеру, два первичных, основных значения?

Comment: У омонимов два, а порой и три, первичных значения.

Comment: @Сибиряк ну да. Только слова разные, вот что жаль.

Comment: А как насчет слова 'хрен'? Ни хрена не видно. Хрен тебе. Хрен с ним. Хрен поймешь. Хреново. Охрененно. И так далее. Где тут переносные значения?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятны критерии, по которым следует определять был перенос или нет. Думаю, что таких вариантов, к которым нельзя было бы "придраться", не должно существовать. Я хочу предложить два слова (оба – новообразования, но из разных эпох), каждое из которых было самостоятельно образовано из близких корней, но ни в том, ни в другом случае не было переносным значением, насколько я могу судить. Ниже цитаты из этимологического словаря Шапошникова А.К.

> Баранка – булочное изделие в виде кольца, выпеченное из заварного теста
>   ...
>   Собств.-рус. новообразование с суф. -ка (-ъка) от унаследованного
>   из праслав. *баранъ со знач. «напоминающая бараний рог».
>
> Баранка – простореч. рулевое колесо автомобиля. Новейшее знач. – из
>   проф. арго водителей, а там – из говоров, где баран означал дугу или
>   кольцо, использ. в конструкции саней, бороны, воза для крепления
>   оглобли. Установилось под влиянием выражения «согнуть в бараний рог».

Comment: Нет, здесь очевидная метонимия — баранка кругла, равно как и руль автомобиля, т. е. имел место перенос значения.

Comment: @Aer Ну, это не я выдумал :) Вам следует сообщить правильную этимологию Шапошникову и авторам других этимологических словарей, которые придерживаются той же версии. Странно, что они не заметили такой очевидной метономии.

Comment: У Шапошникова все вполне приемлемо, хотя о баранке в любых значениях этимологи не имеют единого мнения. В говорах-то бараном дугу называли по той же метонимии... Тут все упирается в проблему разграничения омонимии и полисемии, так что, честно говоря, на мой вопрос не может быть бесспорного ответа... Не знаю даже, стоит ли его оставлять.

Comment: @Aer Тогда не спорю. Согласен, что абсолютно чистого примера найти не удастся (я говорил об этом в ответе).

Comment: Проще говоря, я спрашивал, может ли быть у слова два изначальных, первичных значения. Кажется, что нет. В ваших примерах совершенно очевидна последовательность в развитии значений (баранка стала обозначать руль, так или иначе, по метонимии).

Comment: @Aer Хорошо, согласен. Вижу, что я не совсем понял вопрос. Я бы и не пытался – не верю в возможность существования этимологически однокоренных слов, не связанных друг с другом какой-либо диффузией значений.

Comment: Известные бык и пчела — однокоренные слова, однако никакой «диффузии значений» в их истории вроде бы не происходило: оба они разными способами выражают один смысл (животное, которое «бычит»). Но это просто кстати )

Answer (score 1):

Тут, конечно, надо разобраться с формулировками.
Если омонимы - это два разных слова, то что мы ищем-то? Любые два значения слова можно объявить омонимами, даже если они родственные.

Ну а если не считать омонимами близкородственные слова, то как определить, что значение переносное?

Вот, например, слово "ложе". Это и место для сна, и часть конструкции механизма (оружия, например). Да еще ложе - русло реки, ручья...

Мне представляется что это скорее всего одно слово с разными значениями, восходящими к одному корню "лож". И конечно же, никаких переносов значения тут не просматривается. Слова образованы независимо друг от друга.

Хотя, возможно, автор имел в виду "первое и второе значение" одного слова в том смысле, что второе образовано от первого, но тем не менее не является переносным. Мне трудно представить, что это может быть. Разве что фольклорный элемент ("исхитрись-ка мне добыть // то, чего не может быть")

Answer (score 0):

Нет, другое значение слова не всегда имеет переносный смысл.

Например: *долго* — во временном отношении — *сказка сказывается*, и *долго* — по расстоянию — издалека течёт река; вопросы на этом сайте — *текущие* — точно не в переносном смысле воспринимаются.

Как-то шло обсуждение в связи со словом *горчица*. Одно из его значений уже давно стало символическим и, как и другое, — *соль* Земли, уже давно не является вторичным к представлению о соли пищевой.

Обсуждаемыми были слова (самопровозглашённое) *перекус* как форма питания и как неправильный прикус у животных, и не обсуждаемыми словами — пол (чистый) и пол (мужской).

О двух первичных основных... У *сохи*, возможно, оба — основные: (1) кадастровая единица обложения от 3 до 60 дворов и (2) пахотное орудие.

Comment: К сожалению, вынужден не согласиться с обоими примерами: "долгий" изначально значило "длинный" (они даже исторически однокоренные), а пространственное значение, как это нередко бывает, дало временн**о**е "длительный"; с "текущий", кажется, все так же.

Comment: У горчицы изначальное значение «что-то горькое», все остальные — переносные (или даже индивидуально-авторские — «соль земли»), у перекуса история похожая, а пол (чистый) и пол (половина) вообще этимологически разнокоренные, чистые омонимы.

Answer (score 0):

А вот такой пример.

В др.-рус. языке слово ***сторона***  известно с XI века, причем в трех значениях: **бок, край/земля, каждый из двух противников**. Эти значения  сохраняются и в настоящее время, причем к ним добавлено еще и **направление** (от чего-либо).

Конечно, они имеют **общий и.-е. корень** ster/stor – расширять, распространять, но это уже этимология.  Поэтому теоретически у слова всегда есть **одно центральное значение,** хотя бы историческое, в противном случае **при случайном совпадении** фонетических форм мы будем иметь дело **с омонимами**.